# What do I return in a async task when an exception occurs

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous

I have the following code...

```
        public async Task<User> GetUserAsync(string name)
    {
        await using var db = new ApplicationDbContext(new DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>());
        try
        {
            return await db.User.SingleAsync(x => x.Name == name);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //return new User();
        }

    }
```

I wonder what I would return if there is an exception because the query does not find a match from the database? Do I return a empty user object or what is standard procedure?

Answer (score 0):

> what is standard procedure?

It's normal to let exceptions propagate until you have something else you can do with them.